# get text from index page to another using php

Tags: php

is there any way to get text only from a page?
for here's example

i have index.php , page1.php , page2.php

now on index.php i write this below then i will create those page1 and page2..

```
<div id="pg1"><a href="page1.php">Hello page 1</a></div>
<div id="pg2"><a href="page2.php">Hello page 2</a></div>
```

now on page1 and page2 i create divs like this below..

```
<div id="getpg1">WHEN page1.php opened, HERE MOST BE TEXT THAT IS ON index.php on div id pg1. get text from that div</div>

<div id="getpg2">WHEN page2.php opened, HERE MOST BE TEXT THAT IS ON index.php on div id pg2. get text from that div</div>
```

hope you understand. it simply means when a page opened it most get the text that i pointed from index.php

Comment: You don't need PHP for that. You need Javascript or jQuery. I can provide an answer for either of them, though jQuery will be much easier. Just let me know which you prefer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. well, let me try jQuery the way you said

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, took me a moment to fix something here first. So here you go:

On your `index.php` put between `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        var content = $(this).html();

        window.location.href = link + "?content=" + content;
    });
});
</script>
```

And change your divs to:

```
<div id="pg1"><a href="page1.php" class="page">Hello page 1</a></div>
<div id="pg2"><a href="page2.php" class="page">Hello page 2</a></div>
```

On your `page1.php` and `page2.php`, simply use:

```
<div id="getpg1"><?php echo $_GET['content']; ?></div>
```

Comment: thank you sir. it is good but the link becomes like this page2.php?content=Hello%20page%202 and i wanted it without that. the . wanted it like, it gets that text from from database on page1 or page2

Comment: @MmPp If the text is in the database, simply pull it from there on page1 and page2? You can't use `<a href.. />` links to act like a form POST, which would prevent the GET like behaviour. Well technically I guess you could, but that would become some really messy code.